# SoftException in Application.cpp:603:

Tags: runtime-error, cpanel, web-hosting

I have hosted my code on a server `cpanel` installed on it.i only have a `Cpanel` Account access of it,now i am using my admin panel app (hosted on this server account) ,in iframe hosted somewhere else.it works fine for some days now i am getting error

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at webmaster@
```

when i checked my error_log file ,i found this.

**Directory "/home/.." is writeable by group, referer:'http://myIframeLink.com'**

How can i get out of this issue,i also tried by changing the directory .but didnt succeeded.

Comment: /home must be root:root /home/<user> must be <user>:<user> and /home/<user>/public_html must be <user>:nobody
You can show ls -lisa /home/ path and put error without omiting anything?